# Generating a reply when using an outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have the following simplified spring integration flow:

```
int-ws:inbound-gateway ----> int:transformer ----> int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
```

Basically:

1. A web service endpoint is exposed using the `int-ws:inbound-gateway`
2. Messages from this endpoint are put onto the `input` channel (the first `--->`)
3. A custom transformer translates the payload JSON format and adds the MESSAGE_KEY header (required for kafka)
4. The message is placed onto the `inputToKafka` channel (the second `--->`)
5. The `int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter` pushes the message to a kafka topic

The web service operation has a request and a response payload.
The request payload is what I'm transforming into the JSON message.
I would like to return a response payload (which will be marshalled etc) once the message is placed on the kafka topic by the `int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter`

How do I do this?

At the moment, when I invoke the web service everything works as expected, but I have to set a `reply-timeout` on the `int-ws:inbound-gateway` so that it doesn't hang.  When I do this, I simply get an empty response back on SOAPUI.

I understand the concepts in the section [Gateway behavior when no response arrives](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e4776) - but in my case I **do want to generate a response**.

This is my integration context (without the kafka broker config etc):

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-gateway" request-channel="input"
                        marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" reply-timeout="100"/>

<int:channel id="input"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="inputToKafka" method="transform">
    <bean class="com.test.InputToJSONTransformer"/>
</int:transformer>

<int:channel id="inputToKafka"/>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    order="1">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`<int:channel id="inputToKafka"/>`

to

`<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka"/>`

Add a second subscriber to the channel.

`<service-activator input-channel="inputToKafka" ... order="2" />`

Where the service generates the response; it will be invoked after a successful send to kafka.

Do not include an `output-channel`; the framework will take care of routing the service output back to the ws gateway.

Comment: Thanks - it appears as if the response it sent to the second subscriber _regardless of whether the send to Kafka was successful or not_.  Would there be any way to detect an unsuccessful send to kafka, and preferably return an error message to the WS?  I'm guessing not since the kafka call is wrapped in a `Future` and nothing is done with it.

Comment: Only async kafka sends are supported since we switched to 0.8.2. You would need to suspend the thread and set up a consumer to confirm the message arrived in kafka and then release the sending thread.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of a response are you expecting from Kafka outbound channel adapter, remember it is `Adapter` not a `Gateway`

You could however introduce another component, `ServiceActivator` With an input channel `sendToInputToKafka` now your transformer will output to this channel.

Your 'ServiceActivator' should have an `@Autowire MessageChannel inputToKafka` and should manually send a message to this channel programmatically.
After sending that message, you will construct your desired response as a return type of the `ServiceActivator` and a response to your `ws gateway`

Comment: It is generally not necessary to inject framework components (such as `MessageChannel` into user code. See my answer.