# Intercept a Spring integration http:inbound-gateway's replyChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I would like to apply an Interceptor on the `reply-channel` of an `http:inbound-gateway` to save some event related data to a table. The flow continues in a `chain` which then goes to a `header-value-router`. As an example let's take a `service-activator` at the end of this flow, where the `output-channel` is not specified. In this case, the replyChannel header holds a `TemporaryReplyChannel` object (anonymous reply channel) instead of the gateway's `reply-channel`. This way the Interceptor is never called.

Is there a way to "force" the usage of the specified reply-channel? [The Spring document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel) states that

> by defining a default-reply-channel you can point to a channel of your choosing, which in this case would be a publish-subscribe-channel. The Gateway would create a bridge from it to the temporary, anonymous reply channel that is stored in the header.

I've tried using a `publish-subscribe-channel` as `reply-channel`, but it didn't make any difference. Maybe I misunderstood the article...

Inside my chain I've also experimented with a `header-enricher`. I wanted to overwrite the value of the replyChannel with the id of the channel I want to intercept (submit.reply.channel). While debugging I was able to see "submit.reply.channel" in the header, but then I got an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/NoRollbackRuleAttribute` and stopped trying ;-)

Code snippets

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="submitHttpGateway"
    request-channel="submit.request.channel" reply-channel="submit.reply.channel" path="/submit" supported-methods="GET">
    <int-http:header name="requestAttributes" expression="#requestAttributes" />
    <int-http:header name="requestParametersMap" expression="#requestParams" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="submit.request.channel" />
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="submit.reply.channel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:ref bean="replyChannelInterceptor" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:publish-subscribe-channel>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "easy" way is to explicitly send the reply via the `output-channel` on the last endpoint.

In fact, all that happens when you send to a declared channel is the reply channel is simply bridged to the `replyChannel` header.

You could do it by saving off the `replyChannel` header in another header, set the `replyChannel` header to some other channel (which you can intercept); then restore the `replyChannel` header to the saved-off channel before the reply is returned to the gateway.

**EDIT:**

Sample config...

```
<int:channel id="in" />

<int:header-enricher input-channel="in" output-channel="next">
    <int:header name="origReplyChannel" expression="headers['replyChannel']"/>
    <int:reply-channel ref="myReplies" overwrite="true" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:router input-channel="next" expression="payload.equals('foo')">
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="channel1" />
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="channel2" />
</int:router>

<int:transformer input-channel="channel1" expression="payload.toUpperCase()" />

<int:transformer input-channel="channel2" expression="payload + payload" />

<int:channel id="myReplies" />

<!-- restore the reply channel -->
<int:header-enricher input-channel="myReplies" output-channel="tapped">
    <int:reply-channel expression="headers['origReplyChannel']" overwrite="true" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="tapped">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" logger-name="tapInbound"
    level="INFO" />

<!-- route reply -->
<int:bridge id="bridgeToNowhere" input-channel="tapped" />
```

Test:

```
MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("in", MessageChannel.class);
MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate(channel);
String reply = template.convertSendAndReceive("foo", String.class);
System.out.println(reply);
reply = template.convertSendAndReceive("bar", String.class);
System.out.println(reply);  }
```

Result:

```
09:36:30.224 INFO  [main][tapInbound] GenericMessage [payload=FOO, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@fba92d3, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@fba92d3, id=326a610f-80c6-5b74-0158-e3644b732aab, origReplyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@fba92d3, timestamp=1442496990223}]
FOO
09:36:30.227 INFO  [main][tapInbound] GenericMessage [payload=barbar, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@662b4c69, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@662b4c69, id=d161917c-ca73-a5a9-d0f1-d7a4346a459e, origReplyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@662b4c69, timestamp=1442496990227}]
barbar
```

Comment: The last part of your answer sounds promising but I'm afraid it cannot be applied to my situation. The last element in my context is a `header-value-router` that contains 10+ mappings to other channels. In order to store all the info I need, I have to have a point to intercept after the mapped handler finished its logic. The solution that you recommended should be executed after the mapping but before returning to the gateway. As the router doesn't have a 'shared' `output-channel`, I'm afraid there is no way to append this logic to my flow. I hope I'm wrong and you can correct me :)

Comment: The router is not the last endpoint - by definition it's routing the messages elsewhere. You should be able to do the setup before the router. We're at SpringOne this week; I'll try to find some time to create an example.

Comment: Thank you, Gary. What I meant is that it is the last endpoint in the parent context where I want to intercept the outcome of the mapped channel's execution (behind every mapped channel there is usually another big context with a lot of routing, that is why it'd be hard to explicitly set the `output-channel` for every different flow and endpoint, and that is why I'd like to have a shared join point after the router which I can intercept). I agree that we can save and replace the `replyChannel` header before reaching the router, but what about restoring before returning to the gateway...

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I still have a lot to learn, haha! :)

Comment: I'm trying to prepare the reply sent back to a ws inbound gateway after the original message was sent to a jms outbound channel adapter, but this solution didn't work for me. In such cases like mine the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31073182/4222425) was simpler.